# Network Sharing Win 8 mobile

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I found Network Sharing on Win8 mobile. (nokia Lumia)...I am trying to write similar application for Win8. But could not find any support on windows website. On Nokia website also, all  I could find is how to turn on, but nothing else.

So, I have a lot of questions in my mind:

1. Is Network sharing is even supported by Windows or is it Nokia that has their own app to do this?
2. How this network sharing works? Are we tethering WLAN or something else?
3. Is it possible to write a similar app with the existing Win8 mobile APIs provided?
4. Does it use DNSMasq? ( I am assuming it is)

Is there any possible way to find the installed apps and the app structures in Win8 phone, like we have in android phones.

Answer (score 0):

1. Network sharing is fully implemented by WP8 OS but it is under tight control from your cellular operator. You need to pay extra to enable "tethering" (here in USA). The cellular connection (4G, LTE) is then shared and your phone turns into Wi-Fi access point for other devices. When I try to enable network sharing on my HTC 8X (I am not paying for tethering), the screen flics with Wi-Fi details - tells me Wi-Fi broadcast name, password and number of guests connected - and then one second later I get a dialog from T-Mobile to go online and add tethering to my phone plan.
2. See above.
3. No, I don't think it is possible. As an app you don't have any control over network configuration.
4. I'd assume it provides NAT, DHCP and DNS forwarding. I don't think it uses DNSMasq code directly though. :-)
5. For privacy reasons you can't get a list of installed apps. Only when you are writing apps for enterprises (that don't go through Microsoft Store), you can list other apps signed with the same enterprise key. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207245.aspx.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have hotspot enabled on my phone (Nokia Lumia). What I am trying to achieve is to write an app to enable and disable the hotspot (internet sharing) via my own app. Also, I was wondering if I can get access to DHCP requests being made. But seems no API are available in win 8 SDK